# Gerund or infinitive which is more common at the start of a sentence?

Tags: usage, infinitive-vs-gerund

> Swimming helps us stay healthy.
>   To swim helps us stay healthy.

What's difference in meaning, if any?
If verbs are action verbs, shall I use infinitives or gerunds as subjects?

Comment: It is not usual these days to place infinitives at the beginning of sentences. Using infinitives within sentences is, of course, still common practice: "It helps to swim if you want to stay healthy."

Comment: It helps to swim

Comment: 'It helps to swim' and 'swimming helps' are similar? How? Would you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a gerund or a to-infinitive as the subject of a sentence. The latter is less common.